# Entity is "not a managed type" after migrating from javax.persistence to jakarta.persistence (3.0.0)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

My project for a school assignment is modular and uses maven to build. In order to use jlink i had to move my CrudRepository interface to my "restserver" module, thus seperating my entity class and repository class in two different modules. I also had to switch my annotations from javax.persistence to jakarta.persistence. It seems like spring doesn't recognize jakarta's  @Entity annotation as it did with javax's.

```
@Repository
public interface ReviewListRepository extends CrudRepository<ReviewListItem, String> {}
```

Here is my Entityclass with annotations

```
@Entity
public class ReviewListItem {

  @Id
  private String title;
  private int year;
  private double rating;
 .
 .
 .
```

When running spring with `mvn spring-boot:run`in my terminal i get an error saying it couldn't create any beans and at the end it says this: `nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class reviewlist.core.ReviewListItem`

My tutor said i could configure hibernate's entitymappings manually and remove the annotations but i haven't had any luck with that strategy. Has anybody experienced similar issues when migrating from javax to jakarta?

Comment: Spring Boot doesn't support JakartaEE (yet).

Comment: Do you have any idea when it will support jakarta?

Comment: In about a year, that is when Spring 6 and Spring Boot 3 are released.